# How to solve exception caught by widgets library?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use cached network image to display images in my flutter app, however it shows this:

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one Object or one Object and a StackTrace as arguments.: Closure: () => Null
The relevant error-causing widget was
CachedNetworkImage
lib/widgets/custom_image.dart:5
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**custom_image.dart** -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget cachedNetworkImage(String mediaUrl) {
  return CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: mediaUrl,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
  );
}
```

Please help.

Comment: I tried this package and the code on my ide and ran on my device. I gave a invalid URL so I was getting error Icon on my screen. The only different thing I did was that I used this cachedNetwork Widget on my scaffold body directly unlike you, made a method for that.

Comment: so can you show the code where  you are using the this method.

Comment: yea sure, sorry about that. **post_tile.dart:** `import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/custom_image.dart'; import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/post.dart';  class PostTile extends StatelessWidget {   final Post post;    PostTile(this.post);    @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {     return GestureDetector(       onTap: () => print('showing post'),       child: cachedNetworkImage(post.mediaUrl),     );   } } `

Comment: After doing some research and trial and error. I think the issue is in the package. The error you are getting was a bug in old version of http package and I think your cached_network_image is outdated. Try flutter pub upgarde, resolve any dependency conflicts, do flutter clean, flutter pub get. Also make sure your flutter sdk is updated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research and trial and error.

> I think the issue is in the package. The error you are getting was a
> bug in the old version of the HTTP package and I think your
> cached_network_image is outdated.

```
 Try flutter pub upgrade, resolve any
 dependency conflicts, do flutter clean, and flutter pub get.
```

> Also, make sure your flutter SDK is updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your CachedNetworkImage with a Container.

```
return Container(
width:...,
height:...,

child: CachedNetworkImage(..)));
```

Comment: Hey @Reham Alraee . That does not work.
**custom_image.dart**:
```import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget cachedNetworkImage(String mediaUrl) {
  return Container(
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: mediaUrl,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      ),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: how did you called this function? could you please provide a minimal code?

Comment: Assign a width and height for your container

Comment: yea sure, sorry about that.
**post_tile.dart**:
```import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/custom_image.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/post.dart';

class PostTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Post post;

  PostTile(this.post);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => print('showing post'),
      child: cachedNetworkImage(post.mediaUrl),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: tried assigning a height and width. Does not work.

Comment: change your onTap to be (){print("");}

Comment: Also make sure to use the latest version of the package

Comment: nope, does not make any difference.

Comment: ah alr, gimme a min, its not the latest

Comment: So, does upgrading the package helped?

Comment: bro upgrading the packages and shit is really difficult the whole code shows errors and some of them i cant even solve.

Comment: Do you have any other solutions?????

Comment: What packages did you upgrade? also, could you please provide the errors?